# URLs requested via http on the server must be absolute server rendering

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am working with Angular 4 CLI + Universal and I am getting following error. I remember it should also work with relative path but how can I do this?

> ERROR Error: URLs requested via Http on the server must be absolute.
>   URL: /api/countNewsFeedToday
>       at validateRequestUrl (/Users/Picchu/Documents/em/node_modules/@angular/platform-server/bundles/platform-server.umd.js:99:15)

**HTTP Request call example**

```
 ngOnInit() {



        this.http.get('/isUserLogin').map((res: any) => res.json())
        .subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          this.data = res;
          if (res == 'notLoggedIn') {


          } else {
            this.profileId = this.data._id;

            if(this.data.local){
            this.nameMain = this.data.local.nameMain;
            }


          }
        });
    }
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "smarter-experiences",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Starter application of Angular2 with Express",
  "main": "dist/server/bin/www.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json & npm run _server:run",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "build": "ng build --prod --sm=false --aot  --output-path=dist/client && npm run _server:build",
    "_server:run": "tsc -p ./server && concurrently \"tsc -w -p ./server\" \"nodemon dist/server/bin/www.js\" ",
    "_server:build": "tsc -p ./server",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/server/bin/www.js",
    "buildWebpack": "ng build --prod && ngc && webpack",
    "startWebpack": "node dist/server.js"
  },

  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/body-parser": "0.0.32",
    "@types/compression": "0.0.33",
    "@types/cors": "0.0.33",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.32",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.31",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "@types/socket.io": "^1.4.27",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.29",
    "@types/uuid": "3.3.15-alpha",
    "angular2-material-datepicker": "^0.5.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "async": "~1.5.2",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "latest",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "connect-busboy": "0.0.2",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "cookie-session": "2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "debug": "^2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-jwt": "^3.3.0",
    "express-session": "~1.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "json-schema": "^0.2.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.7.0",
    "method-override": "~1.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "~0.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "mosca": "*",
    "mqtt": "*",
    "multer": "^0.1.8",
    "ng2-mqtt": "0.1.2",
    "node-geocoder": "3.15.0",
    "nodemailer": "4.1.0",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^0.1.5",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.2",
    "stripe": "^4.15.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "system-sleep": "^1.3.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "~3.8.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0",
    "webpack-sources": "^1.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "markerwithlabel": "^2.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.4",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: showing your code can help better understanding the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, an URL requested on server side has to be absolute. It doesn't work with relative URL's.

A good solution is to use [Angular Http Interceptors](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to intercept all http requests on server side and make them absolute like `http://localhost:PORT/isUserLogin`.

Comment: Ok, but I am getting know following error:ERROR TypeError: this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector is

Comment: open a new question since it does not seem to be related the absolute url